# linearLayout not included in R java file

Tags: java, android, android-layout

So I am following a tutorial found here: [developer site](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals#play).

**My code looks like the below**:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

// A simple {@link Activity} that embeds an AdView.
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  // The view to show the ad.
  private AdView adView;

  // Your ad unit id. Replace with your actual ad unit id.
  private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "INSERT_YOUR_AD_UNIT_ID_HERE";

  // Called when the activity is first created.
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Create an ad.
    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);

    // Add the AdView to the view hierarchy. The view will have no size
    // until the ad is loaded.
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
    layout.addView(adView);

    // Create an ad request. Check logcat output for the hashed device ID to
    // get test ads on a physical device.
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
        .addTestDevice("INSERT_YOUR_HASHED_DEVICE_ID_HERE")
        .build();

    // Start loading the ad in the background.
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
  }

  @Override
  public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (adView != null) {
      adView.resume();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onPause() {
    if (adView != null) {
      adView.pause();
    }
    super.onPause();
  }

  // Called before the activity is destroyed.
  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    // Destroy the AdView.
    if (adView != null) {
      adView.destroy();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
  }
}
```

However, I am getting a single unresolved error that is keeping me from testing the app. On the line

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
```

I am getting an error about linearLayout being unresolved. R and R.id are fine. When I look into my R.java sure enough there is no linearLayout. Obviously I don't want to just put it in there, since R.java is generated.

I'm still really new to Android development, and I don't know how to resolve this issue. How do you make things included in R.java? I've tried editing files such as activity_main.xml to include linearLayout, however when I do and I try to run my app I get "Installation error: Unknown Error. Please check logcat for more details.". I don't know what logcat is trying to tell me when I look at it. I have "import android.widget.LinearLayout". I don't know what to do / what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: do you any errors in your resource files? Also post `activity_main.xml`

Comment: Your linearLayout has an id `linearLayout` attribute in the xml ?

Comment: post your layout file.

Answer (score 0):

You do something job about solving this problem. such as

1)May be not identify id linearLayout of LinearLayout 
2)import LinearLayout Class 
3)You do Clean the project.
4)You do delete bin and gen folder